Non-locality of itemize fumbling with \par
For reasons, I have code that puts a hook in cmd/par/after (for this MWE, this will be the stupid \vskip 2cm). I know that many parts of LaTeX interact and redefine \par and this can break hooks, as I already experienced by doing it myself.
This question is about why \begin{itemize}...\end{itemize} has this effect, but has not when that environment is put inside a group, when \begin..\end is already supposed to enclose things in a group.
In detail, consider the following MWE. It turns extra spacing after \par on and off via a hook and works well (there is extra space after test2, test3, test6 and test7).
\documentclass{article}

%\AddToHook{env/itemize/before}{\begingroup}
%\AddToHook{env/itemize/after}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}

test1

\AddToHook{cmd/par/after}{\vskip 2cm}
test2

test3

\RemoveFromHook{cmd/par/after}

test4

%\begin{itemize}
%\item 
%\end{itemize}

test5

\AddToHook{cmd/par/after}{\vskip 2cm}
test6

test7

\RemoveFromHook{cmd/par/after}
\end{document}

Now if we uncomment the itemize between test4 and test5, subsequent hooks are not executed. Note this problem only happens if the hook has been created at least once before the itemize and the mechanism of the failure is likely the same as in the abovementionned Q/A.
But if we uncomment the hooks that are in the preamble, which encloses the itemize in a group, the problem disappears.
I am glad this is the case, but I do not understand why. And if this group enclosure helps containing the fumbling that itemize does, why is this not done by default by the kernel or the article class ?

you shouldn't remove all top-level code in the hook unless you know exactly what is in it. if you want to remove the code later, use a label so you know exactly what you're removing.

but re. the question, I suspect the answer is because this isn't deliberate ....

if you both label the chunk and save the definition of \par, you can avoid the need for grouping ;).

Lists are defined in the LaTeX2e kernel. They use everypar internally. The article class just uses the kernel code to define enumerate itemize etc.  So the answer to the why, is that from a programming concern, one tries to isolate and each function has its own concerns (input output). In your case you should define an new list, like begin{salmon}...\end{salmon}.

@yannisl why? that really doesn't make sense. the OP isn't trying to change what the itemize environment does but only to stop it interfering with hooks affecting later paragraphs. defining a new list won't make any difference. the problem here isn't specific to itemize.

itemize shouldn't alter top-level chunks outside itself. especially since the behaviour is specific to the top-level label. it apparently fails to save the current definition correctly, so it 'restores' a default rather than whatever applied when it began.

@cfr because the par hooks will save the state once you are within the itemize environment and restore it accordingly when you out.

@cfr using hooks to influence something with a list should be done at the \addToHook{\cmd\list/... command or one of its internals. Within a list you have two types of aparagraphs 1) those rendered with \item  (shaped with everypar) and those that are plain paragraphs below them or above them. Once you add something to the hook it influences both of them.

If you can trace the everypar in lists.dtx and change it to use the \par hooks it will perform correctly, including the grouping.

@yannisl but the point is NOT to change the list. the hook is intended to affect what happens outside the list environment. the par hooks do NOT restore the state. that's the point of the question.

@yannisl before the list starts, the code is removed from the hook with \RemoveFromHook. after the list ends, the code is added (again) to the hook with \AddToHook. the result should not be affected by the list and the list should not be affected by the code chunk. the latter is true - the list is not affected by the contents of the hook. but the former is not - the result is affected by the list. and I don't think it should be. especially since it behaves differently if you use any but the default label for the code chunk.

@cfr Sorry yes, but the principle is the same (in reverse) at end of env it clears everypar and restores what the original def of \par, hence the issue.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


Do not mess around with \par.

The effect that you observe with the \begingroup/\endgroup will disappear with the next latex. You can test that already by using latex-dev.

The reason why the group has an effect is that LaTeX tries to suppress indentation after a list if there is no empty line between the list and the following text. It does that with some clever \everypar juggling and a boolean and the grouping destroys that. What exactly does \@doendpe do?
The next LaTeX will smuggled the boolean out of the group.


\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item item
\end{itemize}
some text after the list

{\begin{itemize}
\item item
\end{itemize}}
some text after the list

\end{document}

Output with current LaTeX

Output with next LaTeX


Thanks. I was not aware of this ability of \expandafter to cross group boundaries. That indeed explains why another grouping has an effect.
I would not have to change \par if it came with a hook that is executed even when it is issued in vertical mode, which it is currently lacking.
BTW, the reason for doing this is also detection of blank line after an environment, so thanks for the pointer to @doendpe. I wonder why this is done with everypar-hackery and not modern hooks, however.

The question through me off at first, but the answer is simple!

Why are you adding a hook to the command \par, which is normally the TeX primitive, as LaTeX2e promise is that this never changes any local changes would restore it back to its original definition.

Change to AddToHook/para/begin and then harmony returns to the universe.



No, in modern LaTeX, \par is not the TeX primitive, not even \@@par is, contrary to what the documentation states. The \par primitive is accessible as \tex_par:D.
I will look into para/end and para/after hooks, but my question is not about achieving something, but why LaTeX behaves the way it does.

@ysalmon \par has never been the primitive in lists, so "modern" here would have to mean after 1984

@ysalmon do `\ttfamily
\meaning\par
\meaning\endgraf`  you will see whatever LaTex did it ended up with tex_par:D which is let to the primitive. The docs explain also the difference between implicit and explicit par and when TeX inserts a par on its own and how this was corrected, as it might have been redefined by a user

@ysalmon  Anyway I am not  a very communicator, maybe David Carlisle can explain better.

@David : that is true. What I mean is that contrary to @yannisl statement (re \par) and contrary to the documentation (re \@@par), neither is the primitive from the very beginning (ie. doing a lualatex interactive session and \ShowCommand\par immediately after &lualatex).
